# IRS Valuation to calculate the expected exposure

Tags: irs, exposure

I have several levels of fixed rate swap vs. Euribor 6 months from 2007 up to now. I would like to know how to calculate with these data the fixed and floating leg of the swaps.

[image]

This is a part of the data, and they are swaps receivers.
Once I have both legs, I could calculate the expected exposure.

Thank you so much

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  For the 5y swap observed on 31/12/2007, the fixed leg is 4.60% paid annually with a 30360 daycount, and the floating leg is 6 month Euribor paid semiaanually with a Act/360 daycount.  IS that what you mean?

Comment: My question is related with the procedure, I mean, what discount factor is needed, if it is necessary calculate forward rates,etc.